# Ubuntu with sssd: How to allow user to access smb shares without ssh

Tags: ssh, smb, ubuntu-20.04

I have joined my ubuntu (version 20.04) to my Active directory domain with sssd and net ads.
I also have setup a smb share (on the ubuntu sever), with all the proper permissions.

A user can access the smb share only if I have configured him in my sssd.conf `simple_allow_users` setting. But this grants him also the ability to ssh to the server.

How can I only allow him to smb without ssh?

Answer (score 0):

You could set DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, or AllowGroups in your sshd_config file.  See "man sshd_config" for more details.